# Difference Between __kindof and not using it in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have read the [article](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/objective-c-in-2015-3cb7dab3690c#.j2z0f5m9n) about some new features of objective-C in iOS. However, I cannot get what is the main difference between these two ways:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSArray<UIView *> *someViews;
```

and

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *someViews;
```

For me, they look pretty similar. What is the difference, and when I should use one over another?

Answer (score 20):

To see the full effect of the `__kindof` I would recommend just putting it to use and taking a look at the different outcome:

```
NSMutableArray<UIView *> *views;
NSMutableArray<__kindof UIView *> *subviews;

views = [NSMutableArray new];
subviews = [NSMutableArray new];

UIView *someView = [UIView new];

[views addObject:someView];
[subviews addObject:someView];

UIButton *someSubview = [UIButton new];

[views addObject:someSubview];
[subviews addObject:someSubview];
```

So far for the insertion into the different generic arrays. Both compile and run just fine. No warnings, no crashes.

The interesting part however is reading from the arrays - keep in mind that in the first slot of both arrays is an actual `UIView *`, in the second slot is a `UIButton *`

```
UIView *extView00 = views[0];
UIView *extView01 = subviews[0];
UIView *extView10 = views[1];
UIView *extView11 = subviews[1];

UIButton *extButton00 = views[0]; <-- warning
UIButton *extButton01 = subviews[0];
UIButton *extButton10 = views[1]; <-- warning
UIButton *extButton11 = subviews[1];
```

This will run fine, but give two compiler warnings for the marked lines:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIButton *' with an expression of  type 'UIView *'

The other two lines work as expected. Still of course no crash. But we have some problematic situation present: `extButton01` contains a `UIView *` but looks like a `UIButton *`.

Therefore adding the following

```
NSLog(@"%@", extButton00.titleLabel);
NSLog(@"%@", extButton01.titleLabel);
NSLog(@"%@", extButton10.titleLabel);
NSLog(@"%@", extButton11.titleLabel);
```

crashes as expected on the first and second line. If we remove the entire `views` array we will end up with warning-free but crashing code. And I do not like crashing but warning-free code. Of course warning-free does not guarantee no crashes but removing warnings for convenience sake is not a good idea IMHO.

## Conclusion

Yes, that feature is neat for removing a cast. **BUT** it also removes the possibly helpful warning of mismatched types. If you are 100% sure that your object at index X is of type T then you could go with the `subviews` approach of using `__kindof`.

I, personally, would/will not use it yet - until I come across a really, really good use case which I fail to see yet.

Answer (score 4):

It's all simple.
In the first case you will need write:

```
UILabel* titleLabel = (typeof(titleLabel))someViews[0];
```

In the second you can just write:

```
UILabel* titleLabel = someViews[0];
```

You should choose which way you prefer: implicit or explicit type casting.

Comment: I think that is actually the correct answer but I still feel like that is a disgusting feature. Why would you want that? You cannot be sure that at position 0 there is UILabel, can you? How? Because there are only labels in the array? Then why declare it to contain UIViews in the first place?

Comment: "Implicit downcasting" seems to be the buzzword here. The compiler will know that there might be some descendants and cast appropriately, and will be happy if it finds a suitable interface for methods called.

Comment: @Eiko BUT what happens if there is not actually a UILabel in the first slot?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm totally with you on that . The automatic downcast thing is dangerous convenience. On the other hand, it is doesn't have more issues than manual downcast, just without the boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, it removes boilerplate, but it obscures the fact that there is something going on here that might possibly go wrong. Will wait for a good reason.

Comment: For example if you look at `UIStoryboardSegue`, in old version you will see that `sorceViewController` and `destinationViewController` was `id`'s, now they `__kindof UIViewController*`. It was used for implicit casting. But now you can write `segue.destinationViewController.title = @"Hello";`

Comment: @luk2302 In Objective-C, we typically don't specify the type of objects that an array contains *at all*. Arrays can contain strings and numbers and views and view controllers all at the same time. It's not often useful to put strings and views together in the same array, so most of the time you have more information about the types of objects. But it *is* often useful to have several different kinds of views in the same collection. Telling the compiler that it can expect every object in the group to be *some kind of* view improves safety without making the code unwieldy.

Comment: @gnasher729 not really, my approach would be / is to just not use `__kindof` but to stick with the "regular" generic.

Comment: @Caleb using the generic `UIView*` constraint is awesome and important but I do not see any use in the `__kindof` (yet).

Answer (score 3):

You know how you can declare a variable like `id foo` to indicate that foo a pointer to any kind of object, and that you can then send any message to `foo` without the compiler complaining? `kindof__ UIView* foo` is like that -- it lets you specify that `foo` is some "kind of" view, but you can send any message to `foo` that would be valid for any kind of view without needing to cast. For example:

```
UIView *bar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[bar setTarget:nil];
```

In this case, the compiler will complain about the second line because `-setTarget:` isn't a method in `UIView`. If you want to get that to compile, you have to cast like:

```
[(UIButton*)bar setTarget:nil];
```

`__kindof` lets you avoid that:

```
__kindof UIView *foo = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[foo setTarget:nil];
```

Here you're telling the compiler that `foo` could be any kind of view, which makes it relax a little and lets you call `-setTarget:` without having to cast it to `UIButton*`. You could just declare `foo` as `id foo` and get a similar effect, but specifying that `foo` is some kind of view gives the compiler more information to work with. Specifically it makes it possible to write Objective-C code that plays nicely with Swift, which is more strongly typed than Objective-C.

Comment: With id foo you could call [foo length] without the compiler complaining, which then crashes at runtime. With __kindof UIView* foo you can't. __kindof is just a better version of id.

Comment: @gnasher729 It'd be nice if that were true, but the compiler doesn't actually complain if you write `[foo length]` -- it behaves just like `id`, really, and you still just get an unrecognized selector exception at runtime.